# Is there a way to add listeners in DefaultTabController?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been trying to add listeners when using `DefaultTabController`. However, every time I add a `TabController` in order to get the current index in either `TabBar` and `TabBarView`, I lose sync between them.

This is my code below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: subPages.length,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar('homepage'),
        body: new Center(
          child: new NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                new SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  title: new TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                    labelStyle: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    tabs: subPages.map((String str) => new Tab(text: str)).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: new TabBarView(
              children: subPages.map((String str) {
                return new ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                  children: subPages.map((String str) {
                    return new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: new Text(str),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          onPressed: null,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "lose sync" ? what is it that is not working for you exactly? where is the part where you are using a TabController ?

Comment: @aziza  When you scroll to another TabBarView, it does not show the correct index in TabBar indicator with that of the current TabBarView.

Comment: How did you know that it does not show the right index? Do you mean the content of  TabBarView is not appearing correctly according to the active Tab ?

Comment: TabBarView is appearing correctly, but the TabBar's indicator no longer updates together with  changes in TabBarView. So even if you scroll to another TabBarView, the TabBar indicator no longer changes or updates.

Comment: What is the TabBar indicator ? what do you mean by that?

Comment: The issue is not exactly clear from your description, and the code is just a subset. Is it possible for you to post the whole code to better understand what you are trying to do?

Are you using a DefaultTabController and also trying to create another TabController? If yes, then they will not be in sync. Instead, where you need TabController to add listeners, you can use [DefaultTabController.of](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DefaultTabController/of.html)

Comment: I just removed DefaultTabController and just attached a TabController to both TabBar and TabBarView. Its now working in sync and can be attached listerners, since they are now both using same controllers. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I'd like to agree that posting [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will let the community better understand your question. Per your latest update, you've been able to resolve the issue. Could you provide in the answer section the solution to the issue you've encountered?

Answer (score 8):

I use this:

```
new DefaultTabController(
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
   
      final tabController = DefaultTabController.of(context)!;
      tabController.addListener(() {
        print("New tab index: ${tabController.index}");
      });
    
      return Scaffold(
        ...
      );
    }
  ),
);
```

Comment: This works, but I believe it builds multiple times so you have as many listeners as you do length

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a tabController and a listener (once changing tab, it will be triggered twice)

```dart
class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    this.tabController.addListener(() {
      if (this.tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        print(this.tabController.index);
        print(this.tabController.previousIndex);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

2. Pass it to the TabBar and TabBarView, like:

```dart
TabBar(
  controller: this.tabController,
  tabs: [
   Tab(text: "0"),
   Tab(text: "1"),
   Tab(text: "2"),
  ],
)

TabBarView(controller: this.tabController, children: [...])
```

Comment: You rock. Also it was confusing to me, but you can wrap this in a defaultTabController and still assign the controller in the TabBar and the DefaultTabController will be overruled by the one you declare in this example.